# Samba does not show symlinks

Tags: ubuntu, samba, symlink

I am using samba under ubuntu 14.04 and I try to share a folder which includes a symlink to a directory that lies on an external drive. If I access the samba share from other devices (like android phone or windows PC) it does not show the symlink - everything else works fine.
I found multiple solution suggestions but nothing worked.
Currently I added the following lines in the `global` section before I restarted samba:

```
follow symlinks = yes
unix extensions = no
wide links = yes
allow insecure wide links = yes
```

However it does not change anything. I am aware of the security risks, but in this case it is no problem.
Can anyone help here?

Comment: Could it be SELinux interfering? Try "grep smbd /var/log/audit/audit.log" or "sealert" to check. I believe there are SELinux boolean settings to have certain daemons follow symlinks above and beyond the program's own restrictions.

Comment: I did not install or enable SELinux so I think it should not be active after installing standard ubuntu 14.04, right? I can check the logs later though, just to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly it worked after I rebooted the machine. Stopping samba (I checked it - didn't get a connection anymore) and starting it again doesn't seem to apply the changes.
Do I miss something here, is this expected behaviour?
Im glad though that it works now.

Comment: It's possible the instance handling your connection was still running from the old configuration. Setting `deadtime` can help with this